# Как удалить случайные строки (oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle

Как в оракле удалить из таблицы случайные строки с некоторой вероятностью? Например, чтобы каждая строка с 10% шансом оказалась бы удалена.

Comment: поставтьте в where ф-цию rnd random или что-то такое.

Comment: Так `where DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE< 0.1 `

Comment: @nick_n_a, я так уже пробовал, но у меня почему-то удаляет либо 0 записей, либо (реже) столько записей, сколько вообще есть в таблице. Такое впечатление, что он рандомное значение использует одно и то же в рамках всего запроса. Хотя, если я пишу что-то вроде `select DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE from table_name`, то для каждой строчки разное значение. Не пойму, почему так.

Comment: @Александр В where  предложении `dbms_random` выполнится только один раз для запроса и вероятность, что запрос вообще что-то вернёт или удалит будет 10% при <0.1. В select листе он выполнится для каждой строки, которую запрос вернёт.

Answer (score 6):

Попробуйте так:

```
create table t1 as select level id from dual connect by level<=1000; 

Table T1 created.

delete from t1 
where rowid in (
    select rid from (
        select rowid rid, count (1) over () total 
        from t1 
        order by dbms_random.value
    ) where rownum <= total/100*10
);

100 rows deleted.
```

Или так, что ближе по смыслу к `sample (10)`:

```
delete from t1
where exists (
    select rnd from (
        select dbms_random.value rnd
        from t1
    ) t2 where t2.rowid = t1.rowid and rnd < 0.1
);

99 rows deleted.
```

При использовании функции `dbms_random.value` в подзапросе, алиас её результата необходимо указать в листе выборки. Недостаточно указать его только в `WHERE` клаузе. Если в фрагменте `where exists (select rnd from ( ...` заменить `rnd` на привычные для `exists` - 1, 0 или `null`, то запрос перестанет работать как ожидается, т.к. изменится предикат в фильтре с `RND<0.1` на `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE()<0.1`. То есть, функция выполнится только один раз и вернёт *только одно случайное значение* для всего запроса.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы делал это так:

```
create global temporary table tmp_tab(row_id rowid)
on commit preserve rows;  /* в зависимости от вашей политики фиксирования транзакций */

insert into tmp_tab
select rowid as rid from tab sample(10);

delete from tab where rowid in (select row_id from tmp_tab);
```

PS к сожалению Oracle позволяет использовать `SAMPLE()` только в обычном `SELECT statement`, т.е. следующий вариант работать не будет:

```
delete from tab where rowid in (select rowid from tab SAMPLE(10));
```

> ORA-30560: SAMPLE clause not allowed